# How to authenticate user using attempt method and status?

Tags: laravel

I am using the `attempt()` method to authenticate user:

```
    if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('phone', 'password'))) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Invalid login details'
        ], 401);
    }
```

Problem is I need to check if the `status` field is true in the users table. How to do that?

I have read more the docs and found this:

```
  $credentials = ['phone' => $request->phone, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 1];

        if (!Auth::attempt($request->only($credentials))) {}
```

Comment: ``else if(!Auth()->user()->status){ // account not active }``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow this approach as well:

```
if (Auth::attempt($request->only('phone', 'password'))) {
   //logged in but account inactive
   if(!auth()->user()->status){
     return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Account Inactive'
     ],403);
   }

   //redirect to dashboard
   //user logged in
   return response()->json([
       //data you want to send
   ],200);
}

//login failed
return response()->json([
   'message' => 'Invalid login details'
], 401);
```

Comment: why 403 status code for successful login? I think you forgot to change.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, that was just missed when I copy pasted from above part.